# Salesforce1 & Local Storage

Tags: salesforce1-app

I may be asking for a long shot here but curious if anyone has tried to persist Salesforce1 data in browser local storage for offline usage? Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline Access in Salesforce 1 is supported by default from Summer 14. [Please check this link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1admin/salesforce1_guide_admin.pdf) and Page number - 21

Comment: I mean to ask for offline create and edit. I know SF1 provides read only capabilities but even that's very limited and poor